# Can't find out how to be notified when an event is beginning in Google Calendar?

Tags: push-notification, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm looking into building an external app that does things when a google calendar event starts or ends. Services like IFTT / Zapier seem to have this down pat, but I'm struggling to see where in the Google Calendar API docs they support webhooks/notifications when an event starts/ends, without actively constantly querying/storing upcoming events?

I already reviewed the Google Calendar API, but I'm not seeing a webhook/notification section that states how I could be notified when Google Calendar events start?
https://developers.google.com/calendar/overview

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#making-watch-requests) it shows how to watch an event

> **Making watch requests**
>
> Each watchable Google Calendar API resource has an associated watch method at a URI of the following form:
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/apiName/apiVersion/resourcePath/watch
>   To set up a notification channel for messages about changes to a particular resource, send a POST request to the watch method for the resource.
>
> Each notification channel is associated both with a particular user and a particular resource (or set of resources). A watch request will not be successful unless the current user owns or has permission to access this resource.
>
> Example
>   Start watching for changes to a collection of events on a given calendar:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my_calendar@gmail.com/events/watch
Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab", // Your channel ID.
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https://mydomaina.com/notifications", // Your receiving URL.
  ...
  "token": "target=myApp-myCalendarChannelDest", // (Optional) Your channel token.
  "expiration": 1426325213000 // (Optional) Your requested channel expiration time.
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve it, there is no notification when the event actually starts or ends. I am still struggling with this.